# Bash - problem with using unset variable in a script

Tags: bash

I have following code:

```
VAR1=""
ANOTHER_VAR="$VAR1/path/to/file"
ANOTHER_VAR_2="$VAR1/path/to/another/file"

...

# getopts which reads params from command line and sets the VAR1
```

The problem is that setting the `VAR1` after `ANOTHER_VARs` are set makes their paths without the `VAR1` part. I can't move the `getopts` above those because the script is long and there are many methods which depends on the variables and on other methods. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Can you move the `ANOTHER_VAR` and `ANOTHER_VAR_2` below the `getopts` instead?

Comment: @sbtkd85 He does explicitly say that he can't do that, but equally, I don't understand why on earth that would be. Can you post some more code/a better explaination of why exactly you can't change the order of the operations?

Comment: @DaveRandom The script has over 500 lines and many functions which need the variables and getopts need those functions so the order must be: variables, functions, getopts. The order cannot be simply changed.

Comment: @user219882 Say your program has `count-stuff -d dir [-f|-a]` that counts in file (-f) or another file (-a).  Then you could have in your getopts loop `d) VAR1=$optarg ;; f) function_that_uses_var1` but I would suggest not doing that, and instead doing `d) VAR1=$optarg ;; f) file_to_read=file ;; a) file_to_read=another_file`  using getopts strictly to acquire information about what was entered on the command line but not to do any work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make ANOTHER_VAR and ANOTHER_VAR_2 into functions. The return value would depend on the current value of VAR1.

```
ANOTHER_VAR () { echo "$VAR1/path/to/file"; }
ANOTHER_VAR_2 () { echo "$VAR1/path/to/another/file"; }
```

Then, instead of `$ANOTHER_VAR`, you'd use `$(ANOTHER_VAR)`

Answer (score 1):

Your 'many methods which depend on the variables' cannot be used before you set ANOTHER_VAR, so you can simply move the definitions to after the `getopts` loop.

One advantage of shell scripts is that variables do not have to be defined before the functions that use them are defined; the variables merely have to be defined at the time when the functions are used.  (That said, it is not dreadfully good style to do this, but it will get you out of the scrape you are in.  You should also be able to move the `getopts` loop up above the functions, which would be better.  You have a lot of explaining to do before you can get away with "I can't move the `getopts` above those".)

So, your fixes are (in order of preference):

1. Move the `getopts` loop.
2. Move the two lines that set ANOTHER_VAR and ANOTHER_VAR_2 after the `getopts` loop and before you invoke any function that depends on them.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to set the ANOTHER_VAR and ANOTHER_VAR_2 variables below where `getopts` is called? Also, how about setting the ANOTHER_VAR and ANOTHER_VAR_2 in a function, that's called after getopts?

```
foobar(){
  do something
  return
}
foobar()
```